# Color in MathJax

Tags: css, mathjax

I want to display questions on my blog in red in color and answers in blue in color. In questions and answers I am using MathJax 2 to render MathML.
I am controlling the coloring of MathJax using CSS like this.

```css
h3, h2, h4, h5
{
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Verdana;
}

.question
{
    text-align: left;
    color: Red;

}

.centerit
{
    color: Blue;
    text-align: center;
}
```

that works perfectly fine in IE, but in Firefox it always displays the MathJax in black color. Is there any workaround to resolve this issue?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are testing your site locally using a `file://` URL, then Firefox's same-origin policy probably is forcing MathJax to use image fonts rather than web fonts.  See the [MathJax FAQ](http://www.mathjax.org/resources/faqs/#image-fonts) entry on this, in particular the section on Firefox local `@font-face`.  One solution is to install the MathJax fonts locally on your computer where you are doing the testing.  The fonts can be obtained from the [MathJax GitHub repository](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/tree/master/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/otf) (click on a font and then on the "Raw" button in the upper right).

Alternatively, you can simply ignore the black color during debugging, as it will work properly once transfered to a live website.

Comment: Firefox local @font-face security feature wont allow to load the fonts therefore CSS cannot be applied. I have hosted mathjax within DotnetNuke and providing the link on the webpage. Is there any work around? I want to be sure thet every thing works fine in test mode before going live

Comment: By installing MathJax font locally , will resolve the issue locally

Comment: Yes, my answer in fact said both of these things: (1) the same-origin security policy is in play for local files, and so MathJax uses image files instead (it knows enough not to even try `@font-face` in that case), and (2) installing the MathJax fonts locally works around the problem since `@font-face` is no longer needed.  I'm glad you got that working, and hope you will accept my answer, as it did give you both pieces of information you needed.

Answer (score 19):

MathJax supports the `\color` macro, but it works differently from LaTeX. In LaTeX, `\color` works like plain TeX commands such as `\bf`, but MathJax takes it as a LaTeX command like `\textbf`.

```tex
\[ \color{red} The whole sentence is red in LaTeX,
   but only the initial T is colored in MathJax.  \]
```

Comment: Better put brackets to make sure the right text gets colored, e.g. `\color{red}{my red equation}`

Comment: current status is that MathJax also colors everything to the end of the sentence or to the next \color{}

Answer (score 7):

If you want to color different parts of an equation different colors (e.g. if you wanted to color-code variables), use `\textcolor` command instead of `\color` to avoid spacing issues.

See the difference:

Using `\textcolor` (preferred):

```html
<script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>

$$
y = \textcolor{red}{\sin} x
$$
```

Using `\color` (makes for incorrect spacing):

```html
<script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>

$$
y = \color{red}{\sin} x
$$
```

Colorized MathJax equations for improved readability demo: [trigids.com](https://trigids.com).

Comment: Note: in version 3 (which you are using) the default for `\color` was changed from the non-standard version used in MathJax v2 to the LaTeX-compatible one in v3.  That means `\color{red}` acts as a switch (it doesn't take an argument), so you get red from there on in your equation.  Note that the $x$ is also red.  That means `{\sin}` is now `\sin` enclosed in braces (not an argument to `\color`), which affects the spacing.  So the spacing is properly handled by MathJax; you just haven't specified what you think you have.

Answer (score 0):

```
$$ y = \color{red}{sin}x $$
```

=

$$ y = \color{red}{sin}x $$

is the answer, but

```
$$ y = \color{red}sin x $$
```

=

$$ y = \color{red}sin x $$

is not the answer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).